# Datatable.Merge doesn't work

Tags: c#, datatable, merge

```
DataTable Table = CreateTableStucture();
DataTable Table_2 = Table.Clone();
Table.Rows.Add(0, "A", "B");
Table_2.Rows.Add(0, DBNull.Value, DBNull.Value, "C");
Table.Merge(Table_2);
```

Why after executing this code object:Table has row with values just from Table_2 and it's not merged as it should. These tables must have the same structure because my program requires it.

EDIT 1.

```
    DataTable Table = new DataTable("table");
    DataColumn KeyCol = new DataColumn("Key", typeof(int));
    DataColumn Col1 = new DataColumn("col1", typeof(string));
    DataColumn Col2 = new DataColumn("col2", typeof(string));
    DataColumn Col3 = new DataColumn("col3", typeof(string));
    DataColumn Col4 = new DataColumn("col4", typeof(string));
    DataColumn Col5 = new DataColumn("col5", typeof(string));
    Table.Columns.Add(KeyCol);
    Table.Columns.Add(Col1);
    Table.Columns.Add(Col2);
    Table.Columns.Add(Col3);
    Table.Columns.Add(Col4);
    Table.Columns.Add(Col5);
    Table.Constraints.Add("keyCon", KeyCol, true);
    DataTable Table_2 = new DataTable();
    Table_2 = Table.Clone();
    Table.Rows.Add(0, "A", "B");
    Table_2.Rows.Add(0, DBNull.Value, DBNull.Value, "C");
    Table.Merge(Table_2);
```

Even that I create them this way it doesn't work.

Comment: Could you please show your CreateTableStucture() method ?

Comment: _These tables must have the same structure_ but in the first table you insert 3 columns and in the second one 4 columns, please show the code of CreateTableStructure

Comment: Try Table.Merge(Table_2, false, MissingSchemaAction.Add)

Comment: Why does your cloned table has one column more than the original table?

Comment: Because the rest of the columns are automatically filled with dbnulls, originally this table have 11 columns. And I'm sorry but I can't show you this method, because it's a few methods which creates this table and they are working perfectly because they were tested thousands of times.

Comment: As is, the code posted should work.

Comment: Well, unfortunately it doesn't

Comment: Put this posted code in a new project and replace the CreateTableStructure with a new function that creates four columns.  The merge will work.  The point is, the issue you are having is with code we can't see.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is you are having a primary key conflict.

```
DataColumn KeyCol = new DataColumn("Key", typeof(int));
//...
Table.Constraints.Add("keyCon", KeyCol, true);
//...
Table.Rows.Add(0, "A", "B");
Table_2.Rows.Add(0, DBNull.Value, DBNull.Value, "C");
```

You have a primary key of `0` for both rows, change the 2nd row to `1` and it should work.

Comment: Well, I know that and it have to be a key conflict. This code has to overwrite every value from Table by corresponding values from Table_2 (only when value from Table_2!=DBNULL). Is it possible to do this by merge or I have to write my own method?

Comment: No, you can not use Merge for it. Merge is designed for adding additional rows to a table, not modifying existing rows in the table.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `Table.Copy()` instead of `Data.Clone()`

From MSDN:

> DataTable.Copy Copies both the structure and data for this DataTable.
>
> DataTable.Clone Clones the structure of the DataTable, including all DataTable schemas
> and constraints.

Comment: I think you are missing the point. The OP need to _merge_ not copy the second one on the first one

Comment: Indeed I misread the question. I thought the OP created the DataTable, Clone to DataTable2, added rows then tried to merge an empty DataTable with DataTable2.